# Identifying geometry storage type in geodatabase stored in Oracle?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, oracle-dbms

How do I identify what geometry storage type is being used with a specific geodatabase stored in Oracle 9i via ArcSDE 9.3.1?

Comment: Can't this vary within the geodatabase? In SQL Server I've used both the default ESRI binary storage format and Microsoft spatial storage datatypes side by side in the same geodatabase. Maybe you have to look at each featureclass?

Comment: I was thinking that it was in the dbtune.sde file and I think it can vary but I wanted to see if I could figure out what was picked when creating the geodatabase.

Comment: The CONFIG_KEYWORD column in sde.table_registry would tell you which keyword was used. Although you could have multiple keywords using the same storage type, so you would need to know something about your dbtune.

Comment: esp in oracle you could have mixed tables. IF you have more that 1 keyword section (dbtune.sde has more than one by default). then which ever one is called on a load, import, or any gp - that is what it goes in as. there is a method to query the metadata (SDEmetadata).

Answer (score 2):

Since the dbtune file can be edited, but not loaded into the geodatabase.  Just use SQL to select the settings from the dbtune table in the database.  That should tell you the geometry storage settings for the different types.